# Code formatter removing required newline

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I am using visual studio code in a vue.js project.

I have Eslint installed, vutur and prettier code formatter.

My problem:

```
1    import Aside from './Aside.vue'
2    import Breadcrumb from './Breadcrumb.vue'
3    import Callout from './Callout.vue'
4    import Footer from './Footer.vue'
5    import Header from './Header.vue'
6    import Sidebar from './Sidebar.vue'
7    import Switch from './Switch.vue'
8    
9    export { Aside, Breadcrumb, Callout, Footer, Header, Sidebar, Switch }
10
```

Pressing <kbd>CTR</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the file gives me this:

```
1    import Aside from './Aside.vue'
2    import Breadcrumb from './Breadcrumb.vue'
3    import Callout from './Callout.vue'
4    import Footer from './Footer.vue'
5    import Header from './Header.vue'
6    import Sidebar from './Sidebar.vue'
7    import Switch from './Switch.vue'
8    
9    export { Aside, Breadcrumb, Callout, Footer, Header, Sidebar, Switch }
```

Resulting in eslint saying:

> Newline required at end of file but not found

This is only happening in .js files.

My settings:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "javascript.format.enable": false,
    "javascript.validate.enable": false,
    "prettier.eslintIntegration": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "prettier.trailingComma": "none",
    "prettier.semi": false,
    "prettier.useTabs": false,
    "prettier.bracketSpacing": true,
    "prettier.jsxBracketSameLine": true
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the same issue described here https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/11
you have to update your vue-loader version to `vue-loader@8.0.2.`

Or use this above the line that is causing the error

```
/*eslint-disable */
```

Comment: I tried installing vue-loader@8.0.2. but that did not do anything. 
Using the comment above works but it is tedious since I have to go through each file and add it. fun fact though is that my collegues do not have the same problem...

Comment: @Ra3IDeN You can still disable eslint https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/73 and remove that particular rule .. also you need to start your server once you apply configuration changes

Comment: I tried disabeling that specific rule but then i got a different problem. On each vue eslint was complaining that the end style tag had its own row so the end result had to be }</style>. I could not add the end style tag on its own line. I can not remove eslint since I have collegues that use it and it works fine for them.

Comment: Well maybe look for the prettify/auto formatting option of vscode and disable it from there